# Why can I do a ternary but not an if statement

Tags: flutter, dart

Why does the first work, but the second does not? The issue with the first is that null throws assertion exception since the widget cannot be null. what is the best practice in this scenario?

```dart
Row(
     children: listOfWidgets != null ? listOfWidgets : null
)
```

```dart
Row(
     children: if (listOfWidgets != null) listOfWidgets;
)
```

Current workaround:

```dart
void List<Widget> _rowWidgets() {
     if(listOfWidgets != null) return listOfWidgets;
}

Row(
     children: _rowWidgets();
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the three options listed has its own problem, so I'll address them individually.

---

**Issue:**

```dart
Row(
  children: listOfWidgets != null ? listOfWidgets : null,
)
```

**Solution:**

```dart
Row(
  children: listOfWidgets != null ? listOfWidgets : [],
)
```

**Explanation**

This is fine except for if `listofWidgets` is null. That would cause the ternary operator to return `null`, and `Row` doesn't allow its `children` property to be null. You need to give it a non-null default value like `[]` instead.

---

**Issue:**

```dart
Row(
  children: if (listOfWidgets != null) listOfWidgets;
)
```

**Solution:**

```dart
Row(
  children: [ if (listOfWidgets != null) ...listOfWidgets ],
)
```

**Explanation:**

This syntax is wrong in Dart because you can't have a nested `if` statement like this. `if` statements have to either exist on their own live of code or (since Dart 2.3) nested within a list/map literal. If you do the nested-in-list-literal route, you will also need the spread operator `...` on the `listOfWidgets` to expand it into the other list. Otherwise, you will end up trying to put a list within a list, which `Row` will not allow you to do.

---

**Issue:**

```dart
void List<Widget> _rowWidgets() {
  if (listOfWidgets != null) return listOfWidgets;
}

Row(
  children: _rowWidgets();
)
```

**Solution:**

```dart
List<Widget> _rowWidgets() {
  if (listOfWidgets != null) return listOfWidgets;
  return [];
}

Row(
  children: _rowWidgets(),
)
```

Ignoring the more glaring syntax errors (semicolon where a comma is expected, dual return types), this one is similar to the ternary issue, albeit a bit more subtly. In Dart, every method that doesn't have `void` as a return type has to return *something*. If you don't explicitly return something, the method will return `null` by default. This is what happens in your `_rowWidgets` method - you don't state what would be returned if `listOfWidgets` *is* null, so Dart will return `null` for you in that case. And just like the ternary issue, `Row` will not allow `children` to be `null`.

---

**Overall Suggestion:**

```dart
Row(
  children: listOfWidgets ?? [],
)
```

**Explanation:**

Ultimately, all you are concerned with is making sure the `Row` receives a non-null value if `listOfWidgets` happens to be null. Dart has the perfect operator for this: the null-coalescing operator `??`. What it does is it returns the value on the left *unless that value is null*, in which case it returns the value on the *right*.

To illustrate it more clearly, the following lines of code perform identically:

```dart
// If option
if (listOfWidgets != null) return listOfWidgets;
else return [];

// Ternary option
return listOfWidgets != null ? listOfWidgets : [];

// Null-coalescing option
return listOfWidgets ?? [];
```

Answer (score 1):

The first case, the ternary has the form `statement? a : b`, and always returns or `a` or `b`. Thats the trick, the ternary always has a return statement even if we cant see it. The `if` doesnt has that statement by default, so you need to explicitly declare the return if you want one.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Is there an empty widget I can return since Row does not allow null children? Or is there a better practice that I am not thinking of?

Comment: You can return a `Container()`. Thats what I do, but maybe exists a better option

Comment: @Ned You could use a null coalescing operator to eliminate the need for an if or a ternary entirely. e.g. `Row(children: listOfWidgets ?? [Container()])`

Comment: Also, this answer doesn't quite answer the question. The reason OP's second solution doesn't work is because Dart cannot do nested `if`s like that. You can use it within a list literal (i.e. `children: [ if(foo) ...]`) but not to the property directly.